# Trouble understanding identity $\mathcal{L}(X_n) = \lambda P^n$ in Nummelin's Markov Chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I've recently started studying Markov chains and I've started reading Nummelin's General Irreducible Markov Chains and non-negative operators. I don't follow the following reasoning made in page 5.

> Consider a Markov chain $(X_n)$ with initial distribution $\mathcal{L}(X_0)=\lambda$ and transition probability $P$. Then:
> \begin{align}
>  \mathbb{P} (X_0 \in A_0  \dots , X_n \in A_n )
>  = \int_{A_0}\lambda(dx_0) \int_{A_1} P(x_0,dy_1)\cdots \int_{A_n} P(x_{n-1},dx_n) ,
> \end{align}
> for each $n \geq 0$ y $A_0 , \dots A_n \subseteq \mathcal{F}$. In particular we have that $\mathcal{L}(X_n) = \lambda P^n$.

I guess the integral identity follows from the Markov property, but I don't understand what the second identity $\mathcal{L}(X_n) = \lambda P^n$ means, nor how to derive it.

Up until this point we have defined a kernel over a measurable space $(E, \mathcal{F})$ as a map $K: E \times \mathcal{F} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ s.t. $K(\cdot, A)$ is measurable for each $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $K(x, \cdot)$ is a measure for each $x \in E$, and a transition probability $K=P$ as a kernel s.t $P(x,E) \leq 1$. After this we have defined $K^n$ by induction setting $K^0(x,A) =\mathbf{1}_A (x)$ and $K^n = KK^{n-1}$, where:
$$
K_1 K_2 (x,A)=\int K_1(x,dy)K_2(y,A),
$$

We also have defined the probability distribution of a $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}')$-measurable function $X:(E, \mathcal{F}) \to (E', \mathcal{F}')$ as $\mathcal{L}(X)(A')=\mathbb{P}\{X\in A'\}$ for each $A' \in \mathcal{F}'$.

So according to this, for each $A \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ the LHS of $\mathcal{L}(X_n) = \lambda P^n$  should be:
$$
\mathcal{L}(X_n)(A)=\mathbb{P}(\{x\in E: X_n (x) \in A\})
$$
now I'm not sure how $\lambda P^n$ is supposed to act over $A$, I guess it would be:
$$
(\lambda P^n)(A)=\lambda(A) P^n(\cdot, A) = \lambda(A)\int P^{n-1}(y,A)P(\cdot ,dy).
$$
What I don't understand is how we can have the equality if the LHS is a number (a probability) and the RHS is a function taking values in $E$. Am I misunderstanding what the expression $\lambda P^n$ means here?

**Edit:** I've now read that we can also consider $K$ as an operator over all $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$ on $\mathcal{F}$ via:
$$
\mu K(A) =\int \mu(dx)P(x,A), 
$$
so I guess that:
$$
(\lambda P^n)(A)=\int \lambda(dx) P^n(x, A).
$$
I still don't see how the second indentity is derived from the first though.